# UnicodeDecodeError ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I just installed python 2.7.13 and Django 1.11.4.
I created a project called myproject and tried to start with the command below but it throws a UnicodeDecodeError error.

```
python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f13229f10c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 128, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 422, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 209, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I didn't configured anything else, just tried to start development server but it fails.

Comment: Please include the relevant database configurations from your settings? You seem to have a non-ASCII database-related name somewhere.

Comment: If you just started, switch to Python3

Comment: Thanks Pieters! Could you please help me how to configure database configurations...I mean which file?   @WombatPM I have plan to use pymqi modules.....not sure Python3 support pymqi modules

Comment: There is this port https://github.com/sky-chen/pymqi for python3, also check out https://zato.io/docs/

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a way to fix above error?

Comment: @WombatPM thanks is there a way to fix above error

Comment: `0xf1` in iso-8859-1 is `ñ`. Any chance you have that somewhere in your code or your database structure?

Answer (score 0):

This Error means

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You have a non-ascii character in the table name.  0xf1 is typically an extended ASCII code for Latin small letter n with tilde.

Strict ASCII only has characters up to 128 (0x80).  Smart programmers realized that they had another 128 possible values in the 1 byte of memory allocated to a character, so they created EXTENDED ASCII.  But everyone had a different idea as to what should be there which lead to CODEPAGES to describe your EXTENDED ASCII scheme.  This has all been replaced by UNICODE which allows every possible character from all real and imagined languages to have their own unique byte value.  How that is in encoded is the subject of various specs such as UFT-8, UTF-16 & ISO-8859-1.

Solution:  Remove the offending character from the table name and life is good.

Comment: Thanks @WombatPM....i haven't created any table so far.... Did the setup and tried to start the server for the first time....so bit confused where non-ascii character coming

Comment: I'd look at File `"/opt/IBM/Python2.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema`
 and see what's triggering the error.  If you are not providing a scheme for the database then it must be coming from somewhere.